# Can't see "SD Card" option in Dropbox 2.4.5.10

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, samsung-galaxy-note-3, dropbox

Version 2.4.5.10 of the [Dropbox app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dropbox.android) adds the ability to export files to SD card.

I have a Galaxy Note 3, and have installed this new version but when I select a file, and choose "Export" and "Save to Device", this is the menu I see:

[image: Save to Menu]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

Is there an option I need to enable or something else I need to do so that the "Internal Storage" and "SD Card" options appear?

Answer (score -1):

The new version took away the ability to go up to external storage device.  Arg.  Why anyone would think this is a good idea is mind blowing.  I am guessing they were just thinking about the iphone when they designed this - that won't allow an external SD card.

Comment: Just the opposite, the latest version was supposed to *add* this functionality.

Answer (score -2):

The option 'Save to device' is an enabled option whether you have or do not have an SD card, once you have chosen 'Export' when you press a filename. If you select this option, and have an SD Card, the first step is to select the button 'Up to Internal Storage', followed by 'Up to Storage', followed by your selection of 'SD Card'.

I have 2 devices, one with, and one without an SD Card. With the SD Card device, the above actions work to allow you to gradually ascend through the tree to find the SD Card, and then descend through that file heirarchy to your desired drop location.

The device without the SD Card allows the same 'Save to device' option but leads you only to other internal storage areas.

On the SD Card device, no settings in Dropbox were necessary for it to appear.

UPDATE 2014/10/21: I found that I, too, lost the ability to Export to an External SD Card right after my Galaxy Tab was updated this afternoon. To restore it, I went to a file in Dropbox, selected a file through hard press until its Activity menu shows, selected Export, which brought me, as you said, to select Recent or Downloads. While this menu is live, select Settings and select 'Display Advanced Devices' and close. The External storage option was re-added as a target location for exporting.

Comment: I do not see the "Up to Internal Storage" option anywhere. If I select "Save to Device" I only see "Recent" or "Downloads" as options, and there's no navigation available.

Comment: ...and yes I have an external sdcard that other applications can see.

Comment: When you view Storage in the device's Settings menu, is your SD Card presented, indicating it is recognized? On a device where the card is unrecognized, it will show the option to Insert SD card, otherwise it will present details of storage use, and the ability to Unmount, and Format.

Comment: Yes, the device sees my SDcard just fine. In Settings it shows "Total space" and "Available space" that match with expectations, and other applications that interact with the SDcard (like File Managers) can navigate the /storage/extSdCard/ directory without trouble. I have also tried a physical reboot of the phone.